# Download txt file via FTP with Async & Promises in Node and AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, async-await, aws-lambda

I am using a single Node module `basic-ftp` to download a txt file in AWS Lambda and place it in the /tmp/ directory within the Lambda function.

I then want to work with the txt file and its contents outside of the FTP function.

I am using Async and Promises and have got a bit lost with the code. The current error returned in AWS Lambda is

```
module initialization error: ReferenceError
      await finalData = (() => {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

resulting from this line `await finalData = (() => {`

Can anyone help fix this and help me access the finalData outside of the FTP function?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var ftp = require("basic-ftp");
var path = require('path');

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

var fullPath = event.line_items[0].meta_data[2].value.tmp_name; // File path on Linux server -------
var myFileNameWithExtension = path.basename(fullPath); // Uploaded filename with the file extension eg. filename.txt

// FTP Function - Download from FTP and write to /tmp/ within AWS Lambda function
example()
//example().then(finalData=> callback(finalData))

async function example() {
    var finalData = '';

    const client = new ftp.Client()
    client.ftp.verbose = true
    try {
    await client.access({
        host: "XXXX",
        user: "XXXX",
        password: "XXXX",
    })

    let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/' + myFileNameWithExtension);
    await client.download(writeStream, myFileNameWithExtension)

    await finalData = (() => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        writeStream
            .on('finish', () => {
            fs.readFile("/tmp/" + myFileNameWithExtension, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                reject(err)
                } else {
                console.log('Contents of AWS Lambda /tmp/ directory', data);
                resolve(data);
                }
            });
            })
            .on('error', (err) => {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err);
            })
        })
    })();
    }
    catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    }
    client.close();
    return finalData;
}

// Output contents of downloaded txt file into console and use in later code outside of the FTP function
console.log("Raw text:\n" + finalData.Body.toString('ascii'));

};
```

Comment: Try using `finalData = await (() =>...`.

Comment: A bit better with that, now shows as ```finalData is not defined```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finalData is only defined within example which returns it, but you're not assigning this to anything. Combined with Luca Kiebel's comment, try adding

`const finalData = await example();`

then log that out.

Because finalData is defined within the function example, it is only available within that function and any function defined within that function.

[You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/scope%20%26%20closures) explains this better than I can

Comment: Right under the line // FTP Function - Download from FTP and write to /tmp/ within AWS Lambda function

You might also have to move this under the example() declaration

Comment: This is looking much better now, just need to figure out how to use finalData further on in the code outside of the FTP function. When I try and log the contents to the console with ```console.log("Raw text:\n" + finalData.Body.toString('ascii'));``` I get the error ```Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined```

Comment: The output of the TXT file is Binary data logged from ```fs.readFile("/tmp/" + myFileNameWithExtension, function (err, data)``` Perhaps that is causing the toString error? Or maybe how the txt file is written with ```createWriteStream```

Comment: Possibly. What is .Body? I don't see it in the buffer docs. finalData is the Buffer obj, so maybe just call finalData.toString('ascii')?

Comment: Don't know where that Body came from. Now outputs with UTF-8. Thankyou so much :-)

Comment: Fantastic! Glad to help